# NFS Sharedfolder in Vagrant (Virtualbox) syncs files extremely slow

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, nfs, vagrant

I have my development system set up with a Ubuntu Vagrant box which includes a shared folder with all the code stuff. My Host system is Ubuntu 13.04 and the Guest is 12.04.

At first all the changes on the Host system are immediately replicated through NFS on the guest machine.
But after a while this slows down to about 1 minute per change.

Only thing I can do is restart my Host system. Sometimes restarting the kernel server and the VM "resets" this slowness.

Any ideas how to cure this. Working like this is a real pain.
Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same issue; running Vagrant 1.4.3 on Linux Mint (Ubuntu 13.10). This is so annoying :(